# Route parameter patterns on routes with similar parameters

Tags: php, laravel-4, routes

I have a few routes that takes a couple of UUIDs as parameters:

```
Route::get('/foo/{uuid1}/{uuid2}', 'Controller@action');
```

I want to be able to verify that those parameters are the correct format before passing control off to the action:

```
Route::pattern('uuid1', '^[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12}$');
```

This works fine.  However, I really don't want to repeat that pattern so many times (in the real case I have it repeated 8 times for 8 different UUID route parameters).

I can't do this:

```
Route::get('/foo/{uuid}/{uuid}', 'Controller@action');
```

Because that produces an error:

> Route pattern "/foo/{uuid}/{uuid}" cannot reference variable name "uuid" more than once.

I can lump them all into a single function call since I discovered `Route::patterns`:

```
Route::patterns([
    'uuid1' => '^[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12}$',
    'uuid2' => '^[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12}$',
]);
```

But that is still repetitious.  Is there a way I can bind multiple pattern keys to a *single* regular expression?

Ideally I'd like to find a way that avoids something like this:

```
$pattern = 'uuid regex';
Route::patterns([
    'uuid1' => $pattern,
    'uuid2' => $pattern,
]);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no built in way to handle this, and I actually think the solution you found is pretty nice. Maybe a bit more elegant would be this:

```
Route::patterns(array_fill_keys(['uuid1', 'uuid2'], '/uuid regex/'));
```

Comment: thanks for the response.  I was really hoping there was a super-secret obscure yet elegant function built just for this purpose that I just could not find.